# Package non-src directories using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, src

Following is pom.xml snippet
[POM.xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgIqG.png)

```
  `<resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
     <includes>
      <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    </resource>
 <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <includes>
      <include>**</include>
     </includes>
    </resource>`
```

Im trying to pull NON-SRC directories into the packaged jar.I have tried doing include,exclude, stuffs . But somehow all directories are getting into target/classes but not into the packaged jar.
Please help how we can do the same. For example copying lib folder to packaged jar.How we can do.

Comment: Please add your POM as text to the question.

Comment: Copying a lib folder into a jar does not makes sense. You have maven which can handles dependencies. If you like to have other files then you can add them via resources but you shouldn't configure the basedir as resources start point better make a separate directory which you add via resources.

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried making separate directory and added via resources.Still the contents of the directories comes under target/classes and not in packaged jar.

Comment: How have you called maven? Please add the information..